# Ad appears (almost) completely blank

Tags: bug, advertising

Well, not completely blank, it does have one black pixel.

[image: Blank ad, with one black pixel]

Is this an ad for Nihilism Inc.?

Second time I've seen this. Firefox 40.0.3, AdBlock is turned off.

Source dump, in case it helps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var divName = "adzerk93278261";
    var inFIF = true;
    var inDapIF = true;
</script>
<script data-ias-script-tag="found" src="https://fw.adsafeprotected.com/rjss/ad.atdmt.com/44484/5965115/i/a.js;p=11087203661815;cache=1442839284737click=http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=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&amp;s=BlSFNPVPtCmftKfYaRtsmHzML-o&amp;url=%u"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://fw.adsafeprotected.com/rfw/ad.atdmt.com/44484/5965115/i/a.js;p=11087203661815;cache=1442839284737click=http://engine.adzerk.net/r?e=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&amp;s=BlSFNPVPtCmftKfYaRtsmHzML-o&amp;url=%u&amp;adsafe_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F14424929%2Fpreserving-order-by-in-select-into&amp;adsafe_type=abdfq&amp;adsafe_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ca&amp;adsafe_type=c&amp;adsafe_jsinfo=,c:oPGoM4,sl:outOfView,em:true,fr:true,pt:1-5-15,wc:1912.168.1280.945,ac:2044.1334.728.90,am:i,cc:...,piv:0,obst:0,th:0,reas:l,cmps:1,br:g,fv:18.0.0,bv:na,dm:na,abv:na,an:n,id:1268d311-605e-11e5-a950-0025904ea176,fm:poVgBuD+11*.44484-5965115,idMap:,pl:AMI3.AMI3.AMI3.noTh.bIab.MtSU.5HJn.xsO9.RKkB,pd:AMI3.nppdf32.dll,rpx:1,lt:6,bl:1,fc:0,rt:0,cb:0,np:0,th:0,es:0,uf:0,tt:jss,et:22,uid:cfe04cd04119785d69e3956a6aa37a,v:1.16.1,sp:0,ct:na,dtm:i,mn:app18,gtpl:0,wr:1280.945,sr:1280.1024,mf:1255236031,ov:0"></script>
<noscript>
    <iframe frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' height='90' width='728' src='https://fw.adsafeprotected.com/rjsi/ad.atdmt.com/44484/5965114/i/a.html;p=11087203661815;cache=1442839284737click=' topmargin='0' leftmargin='0' allowtransparency='1'></iframe>
</noscript>
<object style="position: absolute; width: 1px; opacity: 0; height: 1px; left: 365px; top: 46px;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://static.adsafeprotected.com/detector3.pix">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
</object>
```

Comment: That must be the placebo ad used as a control to test the effectiveness of other ads.

Comment: @aaroninus I noticed this last week, paused the campaigns and notified the client. The issue was resolved and turned them back on. You're saying you saw it again today. I can't repro but if we can get some more info (tags, browser, etc.) I can dig in again.  FWIW: based on the source info above it looks like the same creatives.

Comment: @stevvve Ad appeared on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424929/preserving-order-by-in-select-into) (of course, now a different ad is being shown to me). Could it possibly just be a caching issue?

Comment: Of course, since this is intermittent, I can't tell whether or not the issue is resolved. Is there one particular company whose ad I should see?

Comment: @Aaroninus Caching was my first thought, though I'm not confident about that. The ads in question are promoting Microsoft Azure. Don't see them at all in there.